# como configurar autosave_prefix: de tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Hola necesito saber cuál es el uso exacto de la opción "autosave_prefix:" de Tiny, ya he buscado en la web y en la documentación pero no me explica su uso y cómo configurarlo solo dice que tiene valores de tipo 'sting', me refiero específicamente a los parámetros que se envían dentro de las llaves `{}` en la cadena de texto `tinymce-autosave-{path}{query}-{id}-`.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea #editor", 
  plugins: "autosave",
  autosave_prefix: "tinymce-autosave-{path}{query}-{id}-"
});
```

Por favor alguien que pueda aclararme este asunto.

Comment: ¿Qué parte de [autosave_prefix](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/autosave/#autosave_prefix) es la que no entiendes? Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar tu código y explicar qué es lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: bien ya aclaré la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

En caso de que tu página tenga varios editores se puede utilizar esta función para identificar de qué editor es el "borrador" que se va a guardar. El valor por defecto distingue la ruta (Path) y un id que cubriría la mayoría de escenarios.

Es decir, en el `string` que vas a utilizar lo puedes dejar tal cual está y creará una combinación de ruta (Path), consulta (Query) y un identificador (Id) en un `string` que será el identificador de tu editor.

Estuve buscando más información pero la única página que encontré que menciona lo que escribí anteriormente es [esta](http://tinymce.ax-z.cn/plugins/autosave.php), pero está en Chino. Si utilizas Google Translate puedes ver lo que dice (Que básicamente es lo que puse).

En general, podrías escribir cualquier `string` para crear un identificador para tu editor, por ejemplo si tienes 2 editores y a cada uno les pones autosave_prefix `editor1` y `editor2` entonces será suficiente para identificarlos.

**Edición:** En el sitio de GitHub del proyecto ([aquí](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/25c5e78deb665fa16e8aa91c1436173afbfb7b8b/modules/tinymce/src/plugins/autosave/test/ts/browser/ShouldRestoreWhenEmptyTest.ts)), hay una parte donde muestran como generan un `autosave_prefix` (Líneas 13-18)

```
const testingPrefix = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  const settings = {
    base_url: '/project/tinymce/js/tinymce',
    plugins: 'autosave',
    autosave_prefix: testingPrefix
  };
```

En este caso generan un `string` alfanumérico.